Navigation doesn't update after value changed (Angular)
I'm currently working on my first Angular project and encountering issues with updating my HTML dropdown menu in the header when a user logs in. Unfortunately, it’s not functioning as expected.
The dropdown menu should show "Login" when the user is not logged in. When the user logs into their account, the dropdown should change to "Details" and "Logout".
Right now, it only shows "Login" in the dropdown menu and doesn’t update when the user logs in.
I have already checked if the observable in login-authentication.service.ts receives the correct value after the user logs in, and it does. However, the subscription in the app.component.ts only updates the status/value of the subscribed observable at the beginning, and not again when the user logs in and the value changes.

I've temporarily placed the dropdown menu in app.component. My observable variable isUserLoggedIn$ resides in login-authentication.service.
Here's my header with the dropdown menu:
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
      <a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink="/kundenkonto">Details</a>
      <a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>

The app.component.ts:
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'auto-kino';
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: LoginAuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isUserLoggedIn$.subscribe(loggedIn => {
      this.isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
    });
  }
}

Login Componenent.ts --> Update
  login(): void {
    this.isFormSubmittedLogin = true;

    if (this.userForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    const { mail, passwort } = this.userForm.value;

    this.loginautService.login(mail, passwort).subscribe(response => {
      if (response.success) {
        console.log("Login erfolgreich");
        this.router.navigate(['/kundenkonto']);
      } else {
        this.errorMessageLogin = response.message;
        console.log("Login fehlgeschlagen");
      }
    });
  }

The login-authentication.service
export class LoginAuthenticationService {
  private isUserLoggedInSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isUserLoggedIn$ = this.isUserLoggedInSubject.asObservable();

  public currentUser: any = {}; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(mail: string, passwort: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.http.post<any>('http://127.0.0.1:8080/loginaut', { mail, passwort }).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          if (response.success) {
            this.isUserLoggedInSubject.next(true); 
            this.currentUser = response.user; 
            localStorage.setItem('isUserLoggedIn', this.isUserLoggedInSubject ? "true" : "false");
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.currentUser)); 
            observer.next(response);
          } else {
            observer.next(response);
          }
          observer.complete();
        },
        (error) => {
          observer.error(error);
          observer.complete();
        }
      );
    });
  }

I've tried adjusting the setup based on suggestions from this post, but my structure of the code was/is a bit different so I could't copy it 1:1. Furthermore the async didn't work as well. I tried that already.
Component inside app.component.html not updating
Any help would be highly appreciated! :)

SOLUTION:
I declared another instance of the LoginAuthenticationService in the login.component.ts in the decorator. Although I already created one in the service itself with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'}) and provide it at the root level of the Angular application. When I delete it it suddenly works.


First of all, for reactive values use, since angular 17, signals, its way more efficient.
Second, your sub in ngOnit revieves both values? init false and then true?


Ok, no idea what signals are. But I will look it up. Thanks .) But guess that won't solve my problem Right?
Nop. Only my start value "false". When it get's updated it doesn't receive "true"


Signals a the new way to go to handle reactive stuff, efficient change detaction. but with your problem. where do you call login and do you subscribe to the observable you get from login?

I just updated my question above. Yes, I call the login method in the login component.ts and subscribe to the server's response at that point.

And you get the console.log(""Login erfolgreich")? and its navigate right?

i updated my post and insert a stackblitz example, how i understand your code.
it works like you expected. But maybe you do sth different?

I get the "Login erfolgreich". But the variable isLoggedIn doesn't get updatet in app.component.ts

Thanks for your effort in creating the StackBlitz! Your code looks similar to mine, except for using an async pipe in the "HTML", right?  Before posting this question, I also tried using an async pipe, but it didn’t work. But as your code works Maybe I did it wrong…
I don’t quite understand what you are doing in the App class I have to say. What does "protected service = inject(Service)" do?

Omg I know why it was not working! I declared another instance of the LoginAuthenticationService in the login.component in the decorator. Although I already create one in the service itself with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'}) and provide it at the root level of the Angular application.
When I delete it it suddenly works. Will update the question with the resolution...
Thank you so much @Marlon for your help!

U welcome :) i wrote u some refactoring tips in chat :)!

Your code works like you wish in my Stackblitzapp. Maybe you see sth thats different to yours. I made an lighter version.

The this.loginAuthenticationService.login().subscribe didn't worked. Because I don't have mail and password in the component...

ah okay, i see, it was only a guess. but yours looks right, looks at this point like your http response don't match your rules or you get an errror.... Do you get a response object with property response.susccess?

By success I get from the console a ""Login erfolgreich" or by failure (success:false) I get the "Login fehlgeschlagen"... So that subscription works.. May I ask what Angular Version you use?

@KajaS. its writtin in Angular 17, wburs?

also i don't understand why you are wrapping it in an extra observable, better approach is to you a pipe with a tap operator for side effekt instead of nestes subscriptions

Angular-Version: 17.3.4.? Maybe there are differences?

You mean the isUserLoggedIn$ observable? I’ve never heard of tap operator before, haha. I am new to Angular. I just googled how to update HTML when a value changes over time, and many websites suggested doing it the way I did. How would you change the code with a tap operator?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
